# Controling code for caret in texarea on Android don't work as expected

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webkit, cursor

I've try to use this code:

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        //input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }
    else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
        range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

taken from [here](http://www.webistrate.com/javascript-set-cursor-position-of-textarea/), and [jQuery caret](http://plugins.jquery.com/caret/) it work fine on desktop but not on Android (2.3). When I've try to delete character the caret don't stay at the end, but land in the middle of the word.

[My demo](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/android.html). The code simply map my cursor and command to caret, with this function

```
    function fakeMobileEntry() {
        if (isTouch()) {
            clip.val(command).caret(position);
        }
    }
```

For testing isTouch return true. Anybody have issues with caret inside Andorid (old webkit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this code:

```
    function fakeMobileEntry() {
        if (isTouch()) {
            // delay worked while experimenting
            self.oneTime(10, function() {
                clip.val(command);
                self.oneTime(10, function() {
                    clip.caret(position);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

and in keydown for backspace I put return true (in my code all keydown shortcuts return false).